# Need to get number from text string + add decimals

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, number-formatting

I've been getting really great info here, however can't find a way to pull this one out:

I need to pull from the cell bellow in a way I end up with: "-5000,00"

```
12 août **It Brothers LLC** , -5.00000
```

To note that the text in bold may differ in number of words from line to line.

Comment: Please specify: Is your number `-5.00000` always after a `,`? Is there always only one `'` in the cell? Do you always want to move the decimal dot three positions to the right?

Comment: I import the info from a pdf file (there is no csv). the number is always after the "," indeed (for some reason it gets misplaced when pasting, it should separate the decimals). The ' only appears if the number is >= 1'000,00. No the decimals needs to be always separate the 2 last digits. Say in another line is 10000, it should be converted as 100,00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that your cell content will have one `.` and one `,` the following formula will transform

`12 août **It Brothers LLC** , -5.00000` to `-5000`:

---

---

`=INT(INDEX(SPLIT(substitute(A2,".",""), ","),,2))/100`

---

Now you have two options to transform the number to `-5000,00`

1. Add ",00" as a string, e.g. with `=CONCAT(A4,",00")`
   However, in this case the output won't be a number.

2.Assign the custom number format to the result cell/column as shown in the images below.

> Be aware that either the number will be shown as `-5000,00` or
>   `-5000.00`  depends on your country Spreadsheet Settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(A2; ",");;2)*1000; "#0,00")
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2; ", (-?\d+)")*1000; "#0,00")
```

[image: 0]